# asp.net mvc partialview @Ajax.ActionLink doesn't work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a view page

my view page

```
<div id="beReplaced">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("please click on me to bring the partial view",
                     "PatrialViewToBeCalled",
                     new AjaxOptions()
                        {UpdateTargetId = "beReplaced",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                        HttpMethod="Get",
                        LoadingElementId = "prgress" })
 </div>
```

i have a Controller

```
public PartialViewResult PatrialViewToBeCalled()
{
    var customer = db.Customers.First();

    return PartialView("PartialViewThatMustBeShow",customer);
}
```

but when i click on the generated link it brings me to a new page instead of
replacing or appending the partial view to the div tag.

**What's the problem?**

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was due to the corrupted unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file.

Comment: You should post this as a solution and close this

Comment: what do u mean by closing? how should i close it?

Comment: Post your solution as an aswer below and mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was due to the corrupted unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file.

Answer (score 10):

It could have been that you were missing the:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the main view. This tells the main view to recognize the ajax helper.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery loaded into your page, why not use the simple jquery get / load method to get the partial view ?

```
<div id="beReplaced">
  <a href="#" id="lnk1">please click on me to bring the partial view</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#lnk1").click(function(){
$.get('/controller/PatrialViewToBeCalled', function(data) {
         $('#beReplaced').html(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Because i'm trying to keep my view clean and make it as small as possible and Ajax helpers in MVC have the power to make complex Statements.

Comment: If i want to keep my views clean, i would stick with unobtrusive principle.I feel this jQuery approach is much cleaner than giving your ajax parameter methods inside the view (where i would like to see only html markup only as much as i can)

Comment: Probably because he wanted to know how to use ActionLink, not how to manipulate the DOM using standard jQuery? :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with ASP .NET MVC 4 make sure that

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

is in the end of the body tag as well.

```
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working on it for too long, thinking it did not work. Viewing the page source didn't show anything either.

Eventually, I found out it actually did work when I saw the successful requests in the console of Firebug. It only was showing it off screen. In the HTML tab of Firebug I finally found the output, even though it does not show up in the page source.