# How to update View using Ajax in asp.net mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a  simple form with drop down list with people names(exhibitors). After I choose one of them and click link “Get Exhibitor data” I want to update only a part of my Home site and show data of chosen exhibitor. 
Structure of my folders in project:[image: Structure-Of-Folders]
My home controller looks like follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }



        public PartialViewResult GetExhibitorDataById(int? Id)
        {
            List<Exhibitor> exhibitors = new List<Exhibitor>()
            {
                new Exhibitor()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    Name= "Tom",
                    Surname="Cruise"
                },
                new Exhibitor()
                {
                    Id=2,
                    Name= "Jennifer",
                    Surname="Lopez"
                },
            };

            if (Id == 1)
            {
                //return PartialView("_Exhibitor", exhibitors[0]);
                Session["ExhibitorData"] = exhibitors[0];
                return PartialView("_Exhibitor");
            }
            else if(Id==2)
            {
                //return PartialView("_Exhibitor", exhibitors[1]);
                Session["ExhibitorData"] = exhibitors[1];
                return PartialView("_Exhibitor");
            }
            else
            {
                //return PartialView("_Exhibitor", new Exhibitor());
                Session["ExhibitorData"] = new Exhibitor();
                return PartialView("_Exhibitor");
            }

        }

        public class Exhibitor
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

My Index View code from Home folder looks like this:

```
@using WebApplication5.Controllers

<h2>Exhibitors</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@Html.DropDownList("ExhibitorsList", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Text ="Tom Cruise", Value = "1" },
     new SelectListItem {Text ="Jennifer Lopez", Value = "2" },
}, "Select Exhibitor" )

@Ajax.ActionLink("Get Exhibitor data", "GetExhibitorDataById", new { Id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "divExhibitors", // ID of the HTML element to update
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace // Replace the existing contents
})

<div id="divExhibitors">
</div>
```

But I would like to set parameter Id of Ajax.ActionLink, to value from DropDownList called “ExhibitorsList” and I don’t know how to do that. 
Partial View code “_Exhibitor” looks like this:

```
@using WebApplication5.Controllers

<table>

    @if (Session["ExhibitorData"] != null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            @*@{HomeController.Exhibitor exhibitor = ((HomeController.Exhibitor)(@Session["ExhibitorData"]))};*@
            @*<td>@exhibitor.Id</td>*@
            <td>@((HomeController.Exhibitor)(@Session["ExhibitorData"])).Id</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@((HomeController.Exhibitor)(@Session["ExhibitorData"])).Name</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>surname</td>
                <td>@((HomeController.Exhibitor)(@Session["ExhibitorData"])).Surname</td>
            </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I tried to run my app and then click Aajax.ActionLink something gone wrong because after I clicked Ajax.ActionLink I go to different url.
Home View:

[image: Home-View]

After Clicked Ajax.ActionLink

[image: After-Cliceked-Ajax.ActionLink]

What I want is to choose person name from dropdownlist, then click Ajax.ActionLink and get data of chosen person(exhibitor) without  any redirect or refresh the site as I wrote at the beginning. Im also curious if it possible to do that only with one View- "Index" without using partialview.

Comment: Use a form (`FormMethod.Get`) and post the value of the dropdownlist. And do not use `Session` - pass the model to the partial view and bind to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. "The problem was due to the corrupted unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file." I found post [asp.net mvc partialview @Ajax.ActionLink doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778002/asp-net-mvc-partialview-ajax-actionlink-doesnt-work) and I had the same problem. I uninstalled unobtrusive-ajax.min.js and intalled it once again. It was good solution in my case and now ajax works properly.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Muecke said you should change your controller ina View to pass model and show it:

Controller:

```
   public PartialViewResult GetExhibitorDataById(int? Id)
    {
        List<Exhibitor> exhibitors = new List<Exhibitor>()
        {
            new Exhibitor()
            {
                Id=1,
                Name= "Tom",
                Surname="Cruise"
            },
            new Exhibitor()
            {
                Id=2,
                Name= "Jennifer",
                Surname="Lopez"
            },
        };

        //here how you pass model to View
        ViewData.Model = exhibitors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        return PartialView("_Exhibitor");
    }
```

Your View will be:

```
@model WebApplication5.Controllers.Exhibitor
@using WebApplication5.Controllers

<table>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>@Model.Id</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@Model.Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>surname</td>
            <td>@Model.Surname</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

What i did is make your View strongly typed with `@model WebApplication5.Controllers.Exhibitor` and then use your model properties to show data.

Comment: Data of user with Id=1 which i get is ok now but still there is redirect from url: http://localhost:55566/Home/Index to http://localhost:55566/Home/GetExhibitorDataById/1 after clicked @Ajax.ActionLink. What about "I would like to set parameter Id of Ajax.ActionLink, to value from DropDownList called “ExhibitorsList” and I don’t know how to do that" ?

Comment: @RazemPonad-kilo, You cannot. You need to use a form (with FormMethod.Get`) and submit the form - `ActionLink()` is razor code that is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. Changing a value in a dropdownlist does not update the url of a link.